# make more than one angular app with the same login page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture

i am working on a project that contains more than one application.
there are finance app and HR app. i think it is not efficient if i loaded all files for finance and HR for a user that will use only one of them.
i need to split them into two separated applications having the same login page and also accessing the tokens from the login services.
any explanation for how could i separate them , how will route work and ng-view work and also accessing of main app data (tokens).

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.

1. Make your HR and finance two html pages.
2. Server redirect to each html page by account type.
3. You can access the same tokens in both html pages because tokens are included in session which is stored in browser cookies. cookies are by default shared in the same domain.

**Update**

I guess you mean to use the same singleton "angular service" in two different instances of "ng-app".

In this case, I don't think it is possible.

My solution means that don't store the tokens inside an "angular service".(I don't think this is normal way because every new tab will create a new "login service", so every new tab requires a login process)

Instead, store tokens in cookies. Use "login service" to get tokens from cookies. In this way different instances of "login service" will get the same tokens

Comment: i thought about it like that in order to  have main app that would have the admin pages for those who will use both of them (finance & HR) and login code that handle the token data and user type and privileges  i don't want to duplicate that code. could i find a solution in that approach ?

Comment: I don't see any duplicated code here, you can make your "login function" a single angular app or anything else. The process of it should be authentication and storing tokens into cookies. After that, you can use any number of different "ng-app"s with the accessibility of the same tokens

Comment: its now okay about the login service what about making one index to the website then loading files for the second app after knowing which to load , or i have to separate them to two html pages with their own ng-app, routes and ng-view ?

Comment: Yes, this is my suggested way. Browser will load all files presenting on a HTML header, at once. If you want to load files(js, css, img) separately, there should be separated HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using local storage (I think that might work).

I found this library helpful:

[ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

As it allows you to interact with localstorage with usual angular binding. That way you can have both apps read the local storage as they are operating out of the same domain.